# Ace editor doesn't work in laravel project

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I use [Ace editor](https://ace.c9.io/) in my Laravel project but it's just white and empty while i use the same code and cdn in codepen -> this [PEN](https://codepen.io/armanshojaei/pen/aPwoGG?editors=1010) and it work fine

JS:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.4.2/ace.js"></script>
var aceCodeEditor = ace.edit("codeEditor");
    aceCodeEditor.setTheme("ace/theme/dracula");
    aceCodeEditor.session.setMode("ace/mode/javascript");
    aceCodeEditor.setValue(`console.log('hello world')`);
```

HTML:

```
<div id="codeEditor" class="codeEditor"></div>
```

Comment: My bet is you are initializing before the target element exists. Any errors in browser console?

Comment: https://github.com/cdnjs/cdnjs/issues/13166

Comment: @charlietfl no my friend, just have a `vendor.js` error in console and It has nothing to do with it

Comment: @AlonEitan no this is not my issue